# How can I place a view on a page?

Tags: 7, views

I would like to add a view at the bottom of a page. Is it possible? How?

Comment: Hi @Kevin and welcome to Drupal Answers. Your question is a little bit ambiguous.  When you say "a page" you man all pages in your site or only a certain page? If is just a certain page, what kind of page it is? A node view? All pages for a certain content type?

Answer (score 1):

You can create block display in your view, then go to the block configuration page (Structure > Blocks) and place your block in a region at the bottom of your page.

Comment: This will make the view appear on every page. Not sure if the OP wants that.

Comment: You can configure where the block should be displayed in the block settings as you can do with every other block

Comment: Ye,that's true. But as a block it ha the same limitations of any block on when should it be displayed. Depending on what the OP wants it will fit or not. That's why I was not sure if the answer was addressing exactly what the OP wanted. Well, and because you didn't explicitly talk about block settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use views_embed_view() function for that.

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7.x-3.x

Pass view machine name, display machine name and optionally parameters. Use "embed" display type for a viewto get config links on front-end when embedded.

Example:

```
<?php print views_embed_view('blog_posts','block_1', $node->nid); ?>
```

You can also use `views_get_view_result()` (similar way) to execute view, get it's output. I.e. if you want to execute it from controller and pass value to template.

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7.x-3.x

Or make "block" display for view and add it as a block. Configure that block to be displayed only on specific page.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) to build that. Through Page Manager, you may create a page with a specific URL (of course) and then use the Panels magic by adding any element you need, including a View anywhere within the page layout you have chosen (works nice with Display Suite or Bootstrap). This specific layout and content will appear only for the specific page/URL.